# Obtaining first character of each string in Array of Strings

Tags: go, slice

I am new to golang and I am trying to obtain the first character of a string in an array of strings. It seems like it would be easy, but I don't know how to approach it. Here is what I have done thus far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func acronym(s string) (acr string) {

    // TODO: Your code here
    var arrayOfStrings []string
    arrayOfStrings = strings.Split(s, " ") //split string s into an array of strings based on space delimeter " "
    for _, str := range arrayOfStrings {
        fmt.Println(str)
    }
    return acr
}

func main() {
    s := "Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster"
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        s = strings.Join(os.Args, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println(acronym(s))
}
```

I want the resulting string to be PGGB I am a bit stuck as I have only looped through the array of strings, but i can't think of something like in java where one has the method/function charAt(). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> something like in java where one has the method/function charAt()

In go, strings are immutable byte sequences with the contents encoded in UTF-8. The string representation is roughly, but not exactly, equivalent to a `[]byte` slice (the distinction is unimportant for the purposes of this answer).

There are various library approaches you can use in go:

- If your string is guaranteed to consist of ASCII or other single-byte characters, you can simply index the string to recover bytes at arbitrary positions. Indexing the string at the `i`th position will return the byte at that location. In your case, this would be `str[0]`.
- If you specifically seek the first *character*, rather than the first byte, and your string may contain higher byte order Unicode code points, you need to decode the string as Unicode accordingly. The [`unicode/utf8`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package provides support for this. Code like the following in your loop in `acronym` will properly decode the first UTF-8-encoded rune of each string `str` for you:

```golang
for _, str := range arrayOfStrings {
    r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(str)
    acr = acr + string(r)
}
```

You should note the documentation for the `DecodeRuneInString` method around error conditions:

> If s is empty it returns (RuneError, 0). Otherwise, if the encoding is invalid, it returns (RuneError, 1). Both are impossible results for correct, non-empty UTF-8.

If either condition is possible in your system, ensure you add appropriate error handling logic to check the return result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I solved it after some more dabbing. Thanks!